# Why does '' apparently evaluate as True in Python

Tags: python

I have:

```
raw_matrix.append([])
for as_string in ' '.split(line):
    if as_string:
        print('as_string: #' + as_string + '#')
        raw_matrix[-1].append(int(as_string))
```

This produces the output:

```
as_string: # #
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "product_of_four", line 27, in <module>
    raw_matrix[-1].append(int(as_string))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

raw_matrix is a 20x20 array of lines of two digit (decimal) numbers separated by spaces.

If I'm reading this correctly, as_string is evaluating to ' ' or '', and I'm getting an exception as a side effect of as_string not being parseable as the side effect of it not containing an int()-parseable digit string.

How can I change things so that Python 2.x (3.x) parses a string of two-digit integers, rather than trying to parse unparseable strings as integers?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line:

```
for as_string in ' '.split(line):
```

is pretty fishy here.  You're splitting the string `' '` on the delimiter `line`, most likely returning the list `[' ']`.  Remember that strings only evaluate to False-y values when they are **empty** (0 characters).  The string `' '` is not empty (it has one character).

You probably wanted to do something like:

```
for as_string in line.split():
    ...
```

which will split `line` on runs of consecutive whitespace.

Comment: You get a +1 from me, as you were first here; not sure why the *3rd* person to address this was given an upvote before us. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- It was probably displayed first because someone has it sorted by most recently active.  That happens sometimes ...

Answer (score 6):

You are using split the wrong way around; split the line, not the `' '` space:

```
for as_string in line.split(' '):
```

By splitting the space character by `line` delimiters, you invariably are going to end up with `[' ']`, not an empty string:

```
>>> ' '.split('10 20 30')
[' ']
```

(the exceptions being an empty delimiter, not allowed, and splitting on `' '`, which gives you two empty strings instead). And the one and only element in the result, `' '`, is a non-empty string, so True in a boolean context.

As for the error message, `int()` ignores leading and trailing whitespace. What is left is an empty string:

```
>>> int(' ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

You probably want to even omit the `' '` argument wen splitting and just split on variable-width whitespace:

```
for as_string in line.split():
```

leaving the first argument set to the default, `None`. Using [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) also ignores any leading and trailing whitespace, always handy when reading lines from a file, those would include a newline:

```
>>> '  10          20\t30\n'.split()
['10', '20', '30']
```

From the documentation:

> If *sep* is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a `None` separator returns `[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Am I correct that .split() also splits between consecutive (non-whitespace) characters, or if I want to split solely on whitespace, do I use something other than .split()?

Comment: You are incorrect; `.split()` splits *solely* on whitespace of at least one character length.

Answer (score 3):

Your `split` statement is constructed incorrectly; it should be `line.split(' ')`.  The way it's written, you're trying to divide up a single space by whatever the contents of `line` are, which is obviously just going to return the space.  That can't be evaluated as an integer.

Answer (score 2):

`' '` evaluates to True because it is not an empty string (there is a space in there).

The problem with your code is that `for as_string in ' '.split(line)` should in fact be `for as_string in ' '.split(line)`